# Is spring mvc more important for all the spring projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, frameworks

I am new bee to spring. I am trying to build an application using JSP and Hibernate with Spring. Is it a good practice to use jsp, servlets and use spring to declare the database connectivity and beans in xml or should i use spring mvc please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever part you need from spring. That is one of the best thing about springframework. If you need to use spring just for data access layer then that is fine use it just for that. If you will use it dependency injection frawework for your project then you can use it that way.

Spring MVC is just a presentation layer part of spring. I have been using springframework for last 12 years and I haven't used SpringMVC until last year. So I recommend you to use what you know best for presentation layer but I also strongly recommend using spring for back-end layer.

Comment: Spring framework release in 2002 so it is 13 years old, so you can not be used it 15 years if you are not friends of Rod Johnson :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework

Comment: yeah you are right correct value is 12. :)